# Historical prices of currencies

Tags: bitcoin-core, altcoin, historical-trade-data

Where can I get historical prices for coins, with the ability to store the information. I understand that most APIs do not allow you to save their information, any that do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at [coinmarketcap](https://coinmarketcap.com/) OR [bitcoincharts](https://bitcoincharts.com/charts/bitstampUSD#tgSzm1g10zm2g25zv). I think it what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the link Adam, they unfortunately do not supply historical data :(

I can however use them for a different purpose, so I am still grateful :)

Comment: Do you need it for all coins?

Comment: I made an edit for the answer, please check the other link.

Comment: Aboslute gold for BTC historical prices! Thanks again Adam

Comment: Adam, do you know where I can get the csv format for exchanges?

So when they allow the user to export their trades, they normally have different formats for each exchange. Do you know where I can get it for each exchange or a large number of them, without actually signing up, making a trade and exporting?

Comment: http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/

Comment: I was referring to the user data, you know if I trade on an exchange, my trade history csv has a specific format?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [cryptoarchive.com.au](https://www.cryptoarchive.com.au) for historical crypto data.